# django allauth redirects to login instead of login on duplicate email

Tags: django, django-allauth

A default behavior of django-allauth is redirect to Singup form when the email retrieved from a social profile matches already existing user's emailid.

Instead, I would like to redirect the user back to the login page with the following message in case of the matching emailid on social login:

*An account already exists with this "EMAIL@ADDRESS.COM" e-mail address. Please sign in to that account first, then connect your "PROVIDER" account. You can sign in using "LIST OF LINKED TO THAT EMAIL PROVIDERS".*

Has anybody made something similar? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hey, were you able to achieve the above functionality?

Comment: Have similar issue. Have you found a solution? Does it allow you to input another email and then produces 'Integrity error, Duplicate entry...'? @PythonEnthusiast maybe a solution from you? :)

Answer (score 1):

To redirect user before sign-up you need to override `allauth.socialaccount.views.SignupView`. Simply alter you main `urls.py` settings:

```
# urls.py
from users.views import CustomSignupView

urlpatterns = [
        # ...
        # Your custom SignupView:
        url(r'^accounts/social/signup/$', CustomSignupView.as_view(), name='socialaccount_signup'),
        url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
        # ...
    ]
```

`CustomSignupView` may look like this:

```
# your_app.views.py
from allauth.socialaccount.views import SignupView
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _


class CustomSignupView(SignupView):
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        social_login_email: str = self.sociallogin.user.email
        provider: str = self.sociallogin.account.provider

        messages.warning(self.request, _(f"An account already exists with this "
                                         f"\"{social_login_email}\" e-mail address. "
                                         f"Please sign in to that account first, "
                                         f"then connect your \"{provider.capitalize()}\" account."))

        return redirect(reverse("account_login"), permanent=False)
```

This custom view simply forbids all HTTP methods except the GET method (which redirects the user).

This solution works only when `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP` is set to `True` (`True` is set by default, see https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html). With this setting, the sign-up form is displayed only when there is e-mail address conflict `->` then redirect the user when `SignupView` is loaded.

**Some background:** I had a similar problem as mentioned by [@horbor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2131517/horbor) in the comment. After the user enters another email (if an email from an external provider is already in use), I get `IntegrityError` on `SignupView`. I still do not know if there is a problem with allauth or with my application. However, bypassing signup is the best solution for me.